# WinAppDriver could not find element sometimes

Tags: selenium, winappdriver

WinAppDriver sometimes find element, sometimes no... I try to log my elements List size, and when I run my test sometimes it return 1, sometimes 0. My code:

```
public class Test {
    public WindowsDriver<RemoteWebElement > driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Program Files\\App\\Bin\\MainFrame.exe");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Windows");
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
            driver = new WindowsDriver<RemoteWebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void listLength() {
        System.out.println(driver.findElementsByClassName("MaskEdit").size());
    }
}
```

In log I see NoSuchElementException:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.04 seconds
```

The application MainFrame.exe always runs correctly but test always returns different result. 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

this may happen if the application may not be properly loaded at time , try adding explicit wait.